# Play video Basic

Tags: python, opencv

im new to python openCV,found this code from openCV page;

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Megamind.avi')
while (cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('MMR3', gray)
if cv2.waitkey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()*
```

Tried to run it but it gives error which after done some digging up, i replaced this line:
"cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Megamind.avi')" with this line:

"cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Megamind.avi', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)"

The program run without error but the video windows("MMR3") was not displayed.

**Im using python 2.7.13 with opencv3 running on MacOs Sierra.
**Megamind.avi is available in the same folder where the code is

Answer (score 1):

your `cv2.imshow` has to be in the whille loop. If your `cv2.imshow()` is outside while loop than it will only display the last frame of you video. Change you code to below code

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Megamind.avi')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('MMR3', gray)
    if cv2.waitkey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```